# How to resolve dependencies in referenced library class

Tags: asp.net, webforms, autofac, .net-standard-2.0

ASP.Net Webforms App (.Net Framework 4.7.2) that has a reference to a dll written in .Net standard 2.0. In the dll I have an interface `ISomething` that has a property dependency to `IAnother`.

Using Autofac. On `Global.asax` `Application_Start` I'm registering the classes that implement `ISomething` and `IAnother`.

On execution I do get `ISomtething` resolved correctly; but its dependency `IAnother` ends up `null` (unresolved, I guess).

I did not add any Autofac lines of code to `ISometing`; Just added `IAnother` as a public Property; I'm expecting both to be automatically resolved by the `Autofac.Web` code. (Is this correct?)

**Edit:**

I changed the implementation of the class that Implements `ISomething` to receive `IAnother` as a parameter in the constructor (instead of being a Property)... and that worked.

`ISomething` is a Property dependency on a WebForm Page. `IAnother` as a Property dependency on the implementation of `ISomething`  <<<---- doesn't work.

`ISomething` is a Property dependency on a WebForm Page. `IAnother` as a constructor dependency on the implementation of `ISomething`  <<<---- this works fine.

I would like to understand why it works one way and not the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property dependency in Autofac is optional, so you have to opt-in for it at registration.

So in your case that would be :

```
builder.RegisterType<Something>()
    .As<ISomething>()
    .PropertiesAutowired();
```